# Getting data from LiteDB

Tags: c#, litedb

I wonder how I console.writeline data stored in my litedb database file.
This is my POCO Class

```
[BsonId]
public int Id { get; set; }
public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
public DateTime Last { get; set; }
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Id : {0}, Updated : {1}, Last Message : {2}",
        Id,
        Updated,
        Last);
}
```

There i insert infomation in db:

```
using (var db = new LiteDatabase(_dbLocation))
{
    var hist = db.GetCollection<MailBoxInfo>("History");
    var mail = new MailBoxInfo
    {
        Updated = DateTime.Now,
        Last = datemsg
    };
    hist.Insert(mail);
    hist.EnsureIndex("Updated");
}
```

And, finally, try to output it:

```
using (var db = new LiteDatabase(_dbLocation))
{
    var hist = db.GetCollection<MailBoxInfo>("History");
    var res = hist.FindById(3);
}
```

Then I get exception

> "Additional information: Failed to create instance for type
>   'TanganTask.MailBoxInfo'. Checks if has a public constructor with no
>   parameters".

Where am I mistaken and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LiteDB requires that your entity class must be `public` with an `public constructor with no parameters`. So, you class must be:

```
public class MailBoxInfo
{
    [BsonId]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public DateTime Last { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Id : {0}, Updated : {1}, Last Message : {2}",
            Id,
            Updated,
            Last);
    }
}
```

Default classes are interal (just `class MailBoxInfo`).